# Same message is populating in the Error as well as Skipped que in masstransit rabbitMQ

Tags: .net, error-handling, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have working consumer/handler background service which is using masstransit.rabbitMq. Everything is working fine. Now moving ahead I wanted to handle exceptions and any exception occured after retry policy exhausted then move those in to specific error queue. Its partially working as message can be seen in the error que but same message is seen in skipped/dead-letter que as well. Why?

I'm using Handler for which I wrote separate handlers with handle method.
like

```
configurator.Handler<T>(cont =>
                {
                   var objectHAndler = (IEventHandler<T>)isp.GetRequiredService<THandler>();
                    return objectHAndler.HandleAsync(cont.Message);
                });
```

And in handler

```
 public async Task HandleAsync(EventMessage eventDto)
        {
throw new Exception("Manual exception to test .");
        }
```

but i can see eventDto in skip as well as in error.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Did tried configuring queue using -- IErrorQueueNameFormatter, IDeadLetterQueueNameFormatter into same queue and can see 2 same messages in the queue. Dont know why.